# Where to put multithread-Tasks code in Django

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller

If I need to run multithread (or multiprocessing) tasks using threading (or multiprocessing) module, where should I put threading-related code? I will need a TaskManager of some sort (which will handle tasks creation and control), Task of some sort (which will not be persistent), initialization of them, and other things. Although I will need some thread-related functions, which are not OOP, but will be used in Thread class and so on.

TaskManager is not exactly Model. It's Controller of some sort. This code is running in sub-thread, this is clearly not a View.
Task is model, but web-unrelated and not database-saved. And it is although running in (another) subthread.
Multithreading functions and so on - are not MVC or OOP at all.
Initialization code of TaskManager - where this should be?

Update: Seems to be that I should put my code in models.py (or any external file). But classes should not be inherited from models.Model. Am I right?